# How to optimize the Join query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

any suggestion for the SQL to optimize this query? if I cancel "

```
AND m.matrix_uuid = 98414860655656981
AND c.courses_uuid = 98481529319063564
```

" it will take 1.182s but if I add this where condition to the query it will take the **60s** or more even timeout. Why?

```
SELECT m.matrix_uuid
     , m.name matrix_name
     , c.courses_uuid
     , c.name courses_name
     , e.employees_number
     , e.employees_uuid
     , CONCAT(e.first_name,' ',e.last_name) Name
     , c.validity
     , c.duration
     , MAX(t.issue_dt) issue_dt
     , MAX(t.expiry_dt) expiry_dt
     , COUNT(c.courses_uuid) refresher
     , c.courses_refresher_uuid
     , t.overall_status
     , t.status
  FROM employees e
  left 
  JOIN courses_taken t
    ON t.employees_uuid = e.employees_uuid 
  LEFT 
  JOIN courses_schedule s
    ON s.courses_schedule_uuid = t.courses_schedule_uuid
  LEFT 
  JOIN matrix_courses mc
    ON mc.courses_uuid = s.courses_uuid
  JOIN matrix m
    ON m.matrix_uuid = mc.matrix_uuid
  JOIN courses c
    ON c.courses_uuid = mc.courses_uuid
 WHERE e.status = 2
   AND COALESCE(e.STATUS, 1) != 0
   AND m.matrix_uuid = 98414860655656981
   AND c.courses_uuid = 98481529319063564
 GROUP 
    BY m.matrix_uuid 
     , c.courses_uuid 
     , e.employees_uuid
```

Comment: Please add database tag (MySQL ?) and post execution plan (ideally EXPLAIN ANAYZE if possible).

Comment: i think u should made an index for every table so it can easily perform your query

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query optimization also require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much optimizing that can be done when the `WHERE` clause involves more than one table.  These indexes might help:

```
m:   (matrix_uuid, name)
mc:  (courses_uuid, matrix_uuid)
mc:  (matrix_uuid, courses_uuid)
s:   (courses_uuid, courses_schedule_uuid)
```

Yes, both directions in `mc`, to give the Optimizer a choice.

Comment: I use index to speed up "CREATE INDEX"

Comment: @BryantTang - What??  No index is used in `CREATE INDEX`.

Comment: Yes, I have not used the index for my database and now I added the index to UUID and speed up the performance now